# Php Shell_exec not works in php 7.3.8 but not in 7.4.33

Tags: php, shell-exec

I have this code :

```
 $urlfile=dirname(__FILE__)."/test.php value1 value2 "; 
 $cmd = 'nohup nice -n 10 php -f '.$urlfile.' 2>&1 ';
 $res = shell_exec($cmd);
 echo $res;
```

It executes a file php by a shell_exec placed in another php file.

I have two macs with two MAMP versions. In Mac A i have mamp 5.5 with php 7.3.8 , in Mac B i have mamp 6.8 with php 7.4.33

The code above works fine in Mac A , but if i run it in Mac B it returns an error :

```
nice: php: No such file or directory
```

It seems that 'php:' it's considered as a part of the file path.

- The file hierarchy is the same form Mac A and Mac B
- I have checked php.ini and shell_exec function is activated in Mac B.

Why i can't run on Mac B ? Maybe it depends on php version ?

Comment: Looks a bit like PHP is not on the PATH on the second MAC

Comment: ok it is resolved, i have to write the absolute url of php executable instead of the alias. RiggsFolly, if you want to answer my question i'll mark as correct.